# Value of an out of cycle defined variable disapperas out of a cycle

Tags: bash, variables

```
cd /var/log
grep "UFW BLOCK" syslog | cut -d ' ' -f 13 | sort -u > pippo.txt
k=0
i=1
ip=""
cat pippo.txt | while read line
do
   (( k += i ))
   ip=${line:4}
   echo "IP " $ip" added to list."
   echo -n "K="
   echo $k
   ufw deny from $ip > /dev/null
done
echo -n "Processed and added  "
echo "$k"
echo " IP via UFW to the firewall."
```

Why the k variabale keeps contenent **into** the cicle and then it loose it? 
During the **while - done** cicle echo prints correct k value, but out of the cicle, after the done line, k is printed always as zero.

Comment: As stated in the duplicate, lose the pipe and use redirection `while read ... done < file`

Answer (score 1):

It is because a subshell is created by the pipe `|`.

The subshell copies the current environment and runs the new code in it.

```
cd /var/log
grep "UFW BLOCK" syslog | cut -d ' ' -f 13 | sort -u > pippo.txt
k=0
i=1
ip=""
# Pipe creates an environment of its own with k=0, i=1 and ip=""
cat pippo.txt | while read line
do
    # The subshell increments its own version of k
    (( k += i ))
    ip=${line:4}
    echo "IP " $ip" added to list."
    echo -n "K="
    echo $k
    ufw deny from $ip > /dev/null
done
# Subhell no longer exists
echo -n "Processed and added  "
# The prior environment prints its version of k which is 0
echo "$k"
echo " IP via UFW to the firewall."
```

You could easily fix this by removing the pipe and doing this to read in you file.

```
while read line
do
    (( k += i ))
    ip=${line:4}
    echo "IP " $ip" added to list."
    echo -n "K="
    echo $k
    ufw deny from $ip > /dev/null
done < pippo.txt
```

This should give you the same effect but leave it in the same shell

**Mini example**

You can see the effect of this subshell behaviour by running the following *one liner*

```
k=0; echo $( (( k++ )); echo $k ); echo $k
```

This prints out `1` `0` where some might expect it to print `1` `1`. This works off the same principle of subshells where the `$( )` is a subshell with an inherited environment.

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by the pipe, consider this minimal example, in which the `k` variable remain also  unchanged:

```
k=0
echo "nothing" | k=5
echo $k
```

This will print `0`. So, If you want this example to work, the easiest way to do it seems to be to store the temporary results into a file (in the loop) and then read it outside the loop.

Comment: But I need the pipe to start the cycle, or bettere... I know only this method to scan a file line per line.

Comment: As I edited, the easiest way is imho to store the `k` variable to a file and then to read it from it.

Comment: considering that the reason for keeping the k value outside the cicle is only to give a ending report, I soved removing the last three code lines ad added a 'wc -l pippo.txt' line :) not smart but works. Thanks for the explanation in any case.

Comment: Yeah, seems legit.. :-)